# How to return an array of structs from one contract to another contract in solidity

Tags: contract-development, struct

I am creating a Course contract which contains some details about the course hosted...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Course{

    string courseName;
    uint256 courseId;
    uint256 coursePrice;

    constructor(string memory _name, uint256 _courseId, uint256 _coursePrice){
        courseName = _name;
        courseId = _courseId;
        coursePrice = _coursePrice;
    }

    uint256 currentEnrollment = 0;

    struct EnrolledStudent{
        string name;
        uint256 id;
        bool isCompleted;
    }

    EnrolledStudent[] public enrollments;

    function addEnrollment(string memory _name) public {
        enrollments.push(EnrolledStudent({name: _name, id: currentEnrollment, isCompleted: false}));
        currentEnrollment++;
    }

    function numberOfEnrollments() public view returns(uint256) {
        return enrollments.length;
    }

    function getAllEnrollments() public view returns(EnrolledStudent[] memory){
        return enrollments;
    }


}
```

After this i am creating a courseFactory contracts which creates multiple Course contracts if the function is called with a specific details and enrollments..
The code is given below..

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Course.sol";

contract CourseFactory{

    uint256 totalCourses = 0;

    Course[] public courses;

    mapping(string => uint256) public getCourseId;
    
    function createACourse(string memory _name, uint256 _price) public{
        courses.push(new Course(_name, totalCourses, _price));
        getCourseId[_name] = totalCourses;
        totalCourses++;
    }

    function enrollAStudent(string memory _courseName, string memory _studentName) public{
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        selectedCourse.addEnrollment(_studentName);
    }

    function getTotalEnrollments(string memory _courseName) public view returns(uint256){
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        return selectedCourse.numberOfEnrollments();
    }

    function getAllStudentsEnrolled(string memory _courseName) public view {
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        selectedCourse.getAllEnrollments();
    }


}
```

now the problem is the last function ***getAllStudentsEnrolled***
I want to select a course contract and return all enrollments from that course.. can anybody help how can i achieve this...

```
function getAllStudentsEnrolled(string memory _courseName) public view returns(EnrolledStudent[] memory) {
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        return selectedCourse.getAllEnrollments();
    }
```

I tried this but its showing error...
*** Declaration Error: Identifier not unique or not found.***

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the issue is maybe a bit tricky at first, but you need to specify the right type of return variable. (EnrolledStudent[] structure).

Here is the fixed code, you can use Remix to play with it.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Course{

    string courseName;
    uint256 courseId;
    uint256 coursePrice;

    constructor(string memory _name, uint256 _courseId, uint256 _coursePrice){
        courseName = _name;
        courseId = _courseId;
        coursePrice = _coursePrice;
    }

    uint256 currentEnrollment = 0;

    struct EnrolledStudent{
        string name;
        uint256 id;
        bool isCompleted;
    }

    EnrolledStudent[] public enrollments;

    function addEnrollment(string memory _name) public {
        enrollments.push(EnrolledStudent({name: _name, id: currentEnrollment, isCompleted: false}));
        currentEnrollment++;
    }

    function numberOfEnrollments() public view returns(uint256) {
        return enrollments.length;
    }

    function getAllEnrollments() public view returns(EnrolledStudent[] memory){
        return enrollments;
    }


}

contract CourseFactory{

    uint256 totalCourses = 0;

    Course[] public courses;

    mapping(string => uint256) public getCourseId;
    
    function createACourse(string memory _name, uint256 _price) public{
        courses.push(new Course(_name, totalCourses, _price));
        getCourseId[_name] = totalCourses;
        totalCourses++;
    }

    function enrollAStudent(string memory _courseName, string memory _studentName) public{
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        selectedCourse.addEnrollment(_studentName);
    }

    function getTotalEnrollments(string memory _courseName) public view returns(uint256){
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        return selectedCourse.numberOfEnrollments();
    }

    function getAllStudentsEnrolled(string memory _courseName) public view returns(Course.EnrolledStudent[] memory) {
        Course selectedCourse = courses[getCourseId[_courseName]];
        return selectedCourse.getAllEnrollments();
    }


}
```

Comment: Dude, i tried it and its working absolutely fine, thankyou... but the problem is we are repeating struct EnrolledStudent in both the contracts, so it is necessary or is there any different better way to achieve this? since it violates DRY principle, Thankyou

Comment: @Crypter No problem, I edited the code.